# How to rebase a PR on a fork that isn't mine?

Tags: git, github

There is a project :

```
slava/NiceProject
```

I'm the project maintainer.

Say a user forked my project so he has:

```
user/NiceProject
```

The user is raising PR from his fork into my project

```
user wants to merge 3 commits into slava:main from user:patch-1
```

Let's say that user is now not responding I want to merge the PR but it needs to be rebased. The user set [allow edits from maintainers](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork).

My problem is that I can't seem to do the push after rebase right.

This is what I did:

```
git checkout main
git pull --rebase
git checkout -b patch-1 main
git pull https://github.com/user/NiceProject.git patch-1
rebase main
git push -f  <---- problem is here
```

When I try to push it says:

```
fatal: The current branch patch-1 has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
    git push --set-upstream origin patch-1
```

The message is right I don't have `patch-1` in origin. This is not my branch.
doing `git push --set-upstream origin patch-1` is not the right way because it will create this branch and push the changes from the user code. This is not what I want.

I want to push the changes into the user original branch in his fork so the original PR will be rebased. I don't want to create a new PR with a copy of the commits.

How can I do this?

Comment: If the original submitter no longer responds, then why *don't* you want to upload the branch into your own repository to create a PR?

Comment: I can but I want to understand how I can rebase his fork should I want to. There are cases when it's needed for example if the PR creator doesn't know how to rebase yet after the rebase he want to do more changes...

Comment: You could create a remote for `user/NiceProject` and use that instead of `origin`. I don't know if you'd be allowed to force-push to an existing branch in a different users repository.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You can if you are the maintainer https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Add the user's fork as an additional remote in your sandbox.

**Details**

When I have situations like this, I add the user's fork as an additional remote in my sandbox. I'm going to call it `user-fork` here, but I would normally use the actual user's GitHub name in the name, so I remember later where it came from.

```
git remote add user-fork https://github.com/user/NiceProject.git
git fetch user-fork
```

At this point, I checkout the branch `patch-1` and by default it will be configured to track `user-fork/patch-1` as its upstream:

```
git checkout patch-1
```

No you can edit the PR as you need. When you are done, just push it:

```
git push user-fork patch-1
```

Of course, this command will only work if the user gave you push permission on their PR's branch, as you say they did. In the comments, you added that this is the default when submitting a PR, so this should usually work.

**Variant**

In your question, you had already checked out a local `patch-1` branch. If you want to keep that sandbox, set the upstream for that branch manually:

```
git checkout patch-1
git branch -u user-fork/patch-1
```

Or you can set the up-stream at the same time as you push:

```
git push -f --set-upstream user-fork patch-1
```

**Cleaning up**

When you're done with this PR, you can safely delete the remote to clean up your sandbox:

```
git remote remove user-fork
```

**PS**: Thanks for the question. I did not realize I might be able to do this. Instead, I've been discarding such PRs and redoing them myself, but it would be much nicer to fix the PR while keeping on record who submitted it and the rest of the metadata in the PR.

Comment: This require also to remove the remote when done isn't it?

Comment: @Slava, my question to you here: where do you see on the GitHub page that you have push access to that branch?

Comment: Well, "require" is a strong word. But yes, it's tidier to remove it when you're done.

Comment: @jonais its the default when you open PR. If someone remove it obviously it won't work

Comment: Jonasis would you be kind enough to post the full list of commands that you actually execute end to end? I'm a bit confused between the commands I posted in the question and what exactly should I change

Comment: Sure, let me polish my answer.

Comment: @Slava done. Let me know if you would like further clarifications.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what is user-fork? is it just a random string that I decide to use? (in my code example there is no such thing so I'm not sure what is the equivalent)

Comment: `user-fork` is the local name I gave to the user's repo. Any string will do. Like `origin`, it's just an arbitrary label you give locally to the remote repo. We think of `origin` as fixed, but it's not, it's just the default. When you add a second remote, you have to pick a name.